# Typescript - Type predicate / Check if instance property matches interface value

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Is there a way to check that an instance property matches an interface property whose value can only ever be a single value?

```
enum ThingType {
  ThingA = 'thing a',
  ThingB = 'thing b',
  ...
}

interface IParent {
  type: ThingType,
}

interface IChildA extends IParent {
   type: ThingType.ThingA;
}

interface IChildB extends IParent {
   type: ThingType.ThingB;
}

const isChildThing = <T extends IChildA | IChildB>(item: IParent): item is T => {
  return item.type === T['type']; // <-- This is invalid
};

const child = {
  type: ThingType.ThingA,
};

// intended usage
isChildThing<IChildA>(child);
```

I can pass in a type to the predicate check, but that seems prone to error and doesn't use any actual information about the type itself to do the check:

```
// works, but this relies on passing in the correct `T/type` pair
const isChildThing = <T extends IChildA | IChildB>(item: IParent, type: ThingType): item is T => {
  return item.type === type;
};

isChildThing<IChildA>(child, ThingType.ThingA);
```

Comment: It's invalid because `T` is a type, and we are trying to use it as a `Value`.

Comment: When do you expect this check to happen, compile-time or runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a check like this

```ts
enum ThingType {
  ThingA = "thing a",
  ThingB = "thing b",
  ThingC = "c",
}

interface IParent {
  type: ThingType
}

interface IChildA extends IParent {
  type: ThingType.ThingA
}

interface IChildB extends IParent {
  type: ThingType.ThingB
}

const isChildThing = <T extends IChildA | IChildB>(
  item: IParent,
): item is T => {
  return Object.values([ThingType.ThingA, ThingType.ThingB]).includes(item.type)
}

isChildThing({
  type: ThingType.ThingA,
}) // yes

isChildThing({
  type: ThingType.ThingC,
}) // no
```

if you want a check for all enums use

`Object.values(ThingType).includes(item.type)` but it will basically product an `IParent` check, so it can be done like

```ts
const isIParent = (item: any): item is IParent => {
  return item.type != null && 
    Object.values(ThingType).includes(item.type)
}
```

Comment: I think it's going to return **true**, always. For example, for this case... `isChildThing<IChildB>(childA)`, keeping in mind the intended usage expressed in the OP.

Comment: @NalinRanjan notice `ThingC`

Comment: Yeap. For `c`, it will return a **false**, but between `A` and `B`, it will not, keeping in mind the `intended usage`. For example, `isChildThing<IChildB>(childA)` wil also return **true**, whereas I think the expected is it should return a **false**,

Comment: yes, depends on what author is testing for

Comment: yes.. also, it is not clear when the check should happen... `compile-time` or `runtime`?

Comment: @NalinRanjan is correct, I would like it to be able to check that the specific interface is matched given the properties of the object, at compile-time. I supposed type predicates could work here

Comment: @EvanWard, so you have your answer then in the code above `isIParent`

Answer (score 0):

How about having an identity function that enforces intended type-constraints...

```
enum ThingType {
  ThingA = 'thing a',
  ThingB = 'thing b',
  ThingC = 'thing c'
}

interface IParent {
  type: ThingType,
}

interface IChildA extends IParent {
   type: ThingType.ThingA;
}

interface IChildAA extends IChildA {
  
}

interface IChildB extends IParent {
   type: ThingType.ThingB;
}

interface IChildBB extends IChildB {

}

interface IChildC extends IParent {
   type: ThingType.ThingC;
}

// const isChildThing = <T extends IChildA | IChildB>(item: IParent): item is T => {
//   return item.type === T['type']; // <-- This is invalid
// };

const reifyThing = <T extends IChildA | IChildB>(item: T): T => item;

const child = {
  type: ThingType.ThingA
}

const childA: IChildA = {
  type: ThingType.ThingA,
};

const childAA: IChildAA = childA;

const childB: IChildB = {
  type: ThingType.ThingB,
};

const childBB: IChildBB = childB;

const childC: IChildC = {
  type: ThingType.ThingC
};

// intended usage
reifyThing<IChildA>(childA);   // Ok
reifyThing<IChildA>(childAA);  // Ok
reifyThing<IChildAA>(childA);  // Ok
reifyThing<IChildAA>(childAA); // Ok
reifyThing<IChildA>(childB);   // Error
reifyThing<IChildAA>(childB);  // Error
reifyThing<IChildA>(childC);   // Error
reifyThing<IChildAA>(childC);  // Error

reifyThing<IChildB>(childB);   // Ok
reifyThing<IChildB>(childBB);  // Ok
reifyThing<IChildBB>(childB);  // Ok
reifyThing<IChildBB>(childBB); // Ok
reifyThing<IChildB>(childA);   // Error
reifyThing<IChildBB>(childA);  // Error
reifyThing<IChildB>(childC);   // Error
reifyThing<IChildBB>(childC);  // Error


reifyThing<IChildC>(childC);  // Error
reifyThing<IChildC>(childA);  // Error
reifyThing<IChildC>(childB);  // Error
```

***Assumptions***

1. Static Checking
2. We are looking for a type-check which is actually a `covariance` closed over `IClassA | IClassB`.

---

---

On Stackoverflow, ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***